# Compiling SuiteSparse (UMFPACK) with Intel MKL on Linux

Tags: linux, intel, lapack, blas, umfpack

I am trying to compile [SuiteSparse](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/SuiteSparse/) with BLAS and LAPACK from Intel MKL. However it seems that make cannot find those libraries. The part of SuiteSparse_config.mk file considering BLAS and LAPACK used by makefile looks like this:

```
# This is probably slow ... it might connect to the Standard Reference BLAS:
#BLAS = -lblas -lgfortran
#LAPACK = -llapack

# NOTE: this next option for the "Goto BLAS" has nothing to do with a "goto"
# statement.  Rather, the Goto BLAS is written by Dr. Kazushige Goto.
# Using the Goto BLAS:
# BLAS = -lgoto -lgfortran -lgfortranbegin
# BLAS = -lgoto2 -lgfortran -lgfortranbegin -lpthread

# Using non-optimized versions:
# BLAS = -lblas_plain -lgfortran -lgfortranbegin
# LAPACK = -llapack_plain

# BLAS = -lblas_plain -lgfortran -lgfortranbegin
# LAPACK = -llapack
```

I tried to copy Intel's libmkl_blas_95ilp64.a and libmkl_blas95_lp64.a into sparse suite folder and setting

```
BLAS = -libmkl_blas_95ilp64
LAPACK = -libmkl_blas95_lp64
```

but then it says that it cannot find such files. I also tried giving a whole path to those libs, but then it compiles everything but demos, which have unresolved errors. How to set those libs to make SuiteSparse work?

Answer (score 0):

```
BLAS = -L/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_rt

LAPACK = -L/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64 -lmkl_rt
```